# Choose Window with Keyboard from GNOME Activities?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

Just recently I switched from Unity to GNOME and I must say I (mostly) very much enjoy it. For example the Activities menu is pretty fancy - I reach it usually by using the Super-Key:
The activities menu will show the various open windows.

Now my question is - how can I select a specific window using a keyboard shortcut instead of having to choose one with the mouse?

---

```
> gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.10.4
```

Comment: Which version of Gnome shell are you using? (you can use `gnome-shell --version`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a extension from [GNOME Extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/). One extensions that should be able to do this is ['windowNavigator'](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/10/windownavigator/). Once installed *(you may need to restart the shell with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then <kbd>r</kbd>, or by logging out and logging in again)*, you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> whilst in overview, and select a window by pressing the number on the keyboard shown in its corner:  [image]